# Rails - Where should I calculate derived attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Noob question for Ruby on Rails- here's an example of my situation: If I have model `circle` and attribute `radius`, where do I do the calculations for `circumference`? Would this be in the model or the controller, and how might it look? `circumference` would need to be accessible in my `views`.

Also, would I be correct in thinking that I don't need to make `circumference` an attribute that's part of my model/database since it can be derived from a user-input `radius`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The logic for calculating a derived attribute absolutely belongs in the model. The circumference is a property of the circle itself, not a concern of how you're presenting it in the web interface.

In order to access the circumference from anywhere, just define a method on the class, such as the following:

```
require 'mathn'
class Circle < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assume `radius` column exists in the database

  def circumference
    Math::PI * 2 * radius
  end
end
```

Since it's pretty cheap computationally to calculate the circumference, you can just calculate it as needed. If it were something that involved more complex calculation that you didn't want to run multiple times, you could memoize it as follows:

```
def circumference
  @circumference ||= Math::PI * 2 * radius
end
```

That would set the `@circumference` instance variable the first time the method is called, then return the result of the first calculation on every subsequent call. If you were doing that, you'd need to make sure to set `@circumference` to `nil` when the radius changed to make sure it's accurate.

```
def radius=(value)
  @circumference = nil
  super(value)
end
```

Comment: Back on point though, I should clarify with my second assumption - I figured I'd need to do my calculations in `app/models/circle.rb`, but would I be able to use `circumference` as a simple variable (ie. `@circumference` instance variable) or would I need to add it as an element of my database table for `circle`?

Comment: If you add this `attr` to your table then you need additional code to ensure that changes to your `radius` also then trigger re-calculation of your `circumference`.  This requires the `def` of the attribute be handled a little differently than in this answer.

Comment: `before_save :recalculate_fields`